"None of these files exist" error while building react native application using Xcode
Recently switched to a mac, so I can build my app for ios. I used "expo eject" to generate my ios file and then built it with xcode. Build is successful but when I open the app, I keep getting this weird error:
None of these files exist:
.expo/.virtual-metro-entry(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx).expo/.virtual-metro-entry/
index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency 
(/Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:114:15)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
  at /Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:169:21
  at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1045:12)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:449:37)
  at async Server._processRequest (/Users/diri/Documents/Agua/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:383:7)

Looked everywhere and tried editing metro.config, but no success...
You can try reproducing it by ejecting app then building with Xcode.
this is my metro.config.js:
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;

